# Oracle SQL updating different record in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have searched and can't find this use case.  I have a table with phone and fax numbers that I need to use to update other records in that same table based on a field in one record matching a different field in a different record.

```
Table named Company_Info
company_ID, parent_company_ID, bank_acct
ABC             DEF             <null>  
DEF             <null>          555444333
GHI             <null>          123456789
MNO             GHI             <null>  
PQR             DEF             <null>
```

I am trying to update the bank acct numbers of the parent company to the sub-company.  For example, bank acct from DEF is 555444333 so I need to update company ABC with that bank acct info, etc.  I have thousands of records in the table.

I can get all of the relevant info into the same temp table like this:

```
  `SELECT subno,parentco,acct,ci.company_ID,ci.bank_acct`  
  `FROM Company_Info CI`
  `INNER JOIN` 
  `(SELECT company_id as subno, parent_compapny_id as parentco, bank_acct as acct`
  `FROM Company_Info`
  `ON ci.company_id = parentco`
```

resulting temp table is:

```
subno,parentco,acct,company_ID,bank_acct
ABC    DEF    <null>   DEF     555444333
MNO    GHI    <null>   GHI     123456789
PQR    DEF    <null>   DEF     555444333
```

My desired end result is for Company_Info table to look like this with bank acct of the parent company populated for all records where bank acct is currently null:

```
company_ID, parent_company_ID, bank_acct
ABC             DEF             555444333  
DEF             <null>          555444333
GHI             <null>          123456789
MNO             GHI             123456789
PQR             DEF             555444333
```

I've tried other iterations of WHERE EXISTS statements etc but for the life of me cannot figure out the right combo to update the table with the bank acct info for a company_id with the info from its parent company.  I always get invalid sql.  I am stuck and would appreciate any help.  I don't believe this is a hard solution but I don't have the knowledge to get it completed.
Thanks.

Comment: "I have table with phone and fax numbers" and your example shows "bank account". Why do you expect to be taken seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one level of parent-child relationships (as seems to be the case here), I think you can just do:

```
UPDATE Company_Info c1
SET bank_acct = (SELECT bank_acct FROM Company_Info c2 WHERE  c2.company_id = c1.parent_company_id)
WHERE bank_acct IS NULL
```

Anywhere the bank_acct is currently null, this will try to find the parent company and use the bank_acct from there. It doesn't matter if a parent company doesn't exist or has a null bank_acct since it will only update ones that are currently null (updating null to null won't matter).

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I was overcomplicating it.  simple is better!